# Java Missing Return Statement - Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, return

I'm writing a program for a library with a class called book which will hold details like author and ISBN. It also has the following method to find the fine due for the book (the rate will be different depending on whether the book is a thriller/romance/etc.)

```
abstract class book{
    //some data
    double findFine(int daysOverdue){
        int rate = 0;
        int fine = daysOverdue * rate;
        return fine;
    }
}
```

Here is one of the subclasses I've written, however it won't compile as it is missing a return statement. I have tried adding the line "return fine;" but it will not recognize it, and it will not let me change the return type to void neither.

```
public class Thriller extends Book {
    double findFine(int daysOverdue){
    int rate = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: the method is supposed to return a double. It doesn't return anything. All it does is defining a local variable and assigning 5 to it. So what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance does not go as far as you think. A method must be complete in itself. (It may, however, call the superclass's respective method, and others.)

You'd better do something like

```
abstract class book{
    //some data
    protected int rate = 0;
    double findFine(int daysOverdue){
        int fine = daysOverdue * rate;
        return fine;
    }
}

public class Thriller extends Book {
    {
        rate = 5;
    }
}
```

or, more Java-like,

```
abstract class book{
    protected int getRate() {
        return 0;
    }
    double findFine(int daysOverdue){
        int fine = daysOverdue * rate;
        return fine;
    }
}

public class Thriller extends Book {
    @Override
    protected int getRate() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `fine` is not a field of the superclass, it's only a method field. So derived classes, or anything outside of this method will not have access to it. And the error occurs, because you don't return a result of type `double` as expected by the method type.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are overriding the method defined in your superclass, then it's best to declare it explicitly with the @Override annotation before the method signature.

Second, you were really just duplicating code. Maybe try:

```
abstract class Book{
    private int rate = 0;

    public Book(int rate){
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    double findFine(int daysOverdue){
        return = daysOverdue * this. rate
    }
}

public class Thriller extends Book {
    public Thriller(){
        super(5);
    }
}
```